# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/util/PythonInterpreter

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jython, classnotfoundexception

trying to use jython in my android project but whenever i start the application i get the following error message:

```
09-29 01:04:24.841: E/AndroidRuntime(2212): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11144
09-29 01:04:24.841: E/AndroidRuntime(2212): Process: com.spitmarks.spitman, PID: 2212
09-29 01:04:24.841: E/AndroidRuntime(2212): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/python/util/PythonInterpreter
09-29 01:04:24.841: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at      com.spitmarks.spitman.TestPythonClass.TestMetoda(TestPythonClass.java:8)
09-29 01:04:24.841: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at com.spitmarks.spitman.MainMenuScreen.paint(MainMenuScreen.java:89)
09-29 01:04:24.841: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at com.spitman.framework.implementation.AndroidFastRenderView.run(AndroidFastRenderView.java:49)
09-29 01:04:24.841: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-29 01:04:24.841: E/AndroidRuntime(2212): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.python.util.PythonInterpreter" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.spitmarks.spitman-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.spitmarks.spitman-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-29 01:04:24.841: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
09-29 01:04:24.841: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
09-29 01:04:24.841: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
09-29 01:04:24.841: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     ... 4 more
```

I am using Win8, Eclipse Kepler, Android SDK 23.

Specified Java class can be found in jython install folder.

P.S. And when i try to debug i get the screen with description that i can not access source code of BaseDexClassLoader.class, and i cant even find it anywhere on my OS.

Every help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

```
package com.spi.spit;

import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;
import org.python.core.*;

public class JythonTestClass {
    public static String Test() throws PyException {
        PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();

        return "";
    }
}
```

This the method i am calling and trying to use in the app (and it breaks while running on the phone)

Comment: do you have `PythonInterpreter` in your manifest file

Comment: No, i don't have it.

Comment: like how, i am new at it, any example would be good.

Comment: you still need help ? did you add the library ?

Comment: Yes i need help, still didnt make it work. Don't know what is happening. I add it as External JAR. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have the JAR on your classpath when compiling and running Jython

- Right click project
- select property
- select add external jar
- clean, build and run

here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort, i'll try this as soon as i get home.

Comment: Unfortunately no success.

Comment: @babazookz how can I reproduce this

Comment: create android project, add jython library and use some class from it. That is what i am trying to do all the time.

Comment: ok can you add some code I can test please , just a little bit

Comment: Yes, i did exactly like that.Thats why i simply cant understand what is wrong.

Comment: Damn i had to leave the office when i get home i will send u a sample project

Comment: Hm, you shouldn't do it. I know i am freaking your mind but i am going through the internet the whole time and no success.

Comment: You can also put a libs folder and paste the jar over there

Comment: Which bersion of android

Comment: Android version is 23